# Why does this partitioning helper view give an 'Input string was not in a correct format' error?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

A database I'm investigating has defined in it a view `admin.View_PartitionRanges`, which is heavily based on the view `PartitionRanges` to be found in [this MSDN blogpost from 2009](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hanspo/2009/08/21/inside-of-table-and-index-partitioning-in-microsoft-sql-server/). The view definition there is follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PartitionRanges] AS
select pf.name as [partition_function],
       ps.name as [partition_scheme],
       1 as [partition_number],
       case when prv.value is null then NULL else '<' end as [relation],
       prv.value as [boundary_value],
       type_name(pp.system_type_id) as [type],
       fg.name as [filegroup],
       case when ps.name is null then NULL else N'IN USE' end as [status]
  from sys.partition_functions pf
  join sys.partition_parameters pp on pp.function_id = pf.function_id
  left join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.function_id = pf.function_id
  left join sys.destination_data_spaces dds
    on dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id and dds.destination_id = 1 
  left join sys.filegroups fg on fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
  left join sys.partition_range_values prv
    on prv.function_id = pf.function_id and prv.parameter_id = 1 and
       prv.boundary_id = 1
 where pf.boundary_value_on_right = 1
 union all
select pf.name as [partition_function],
       ps.name as [partition_scheme],
       prv.boundary_id + cast(pf.boundary_value_on_right as int) as [partition_number],
       case when pf.boundary_value_on_right = 0 then '<=' else '>=' end as [relation],
       prv.value as [boundary_value],
       type_name(pp.system_type_id) as [type],
       fg.name as [filegroup],
       case when ps.name is null then NULL else N'IN USE' end as [status]
  from sys.partition_functions pf
  join sys.partition_range_values prv on
       prv.function_id = pf.function_id and prv.parameter_id = 1
  join sys.partition_parameters pp on pp.function_id = pf.function_id
  left join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.function_id = pf.function_id
  left join sys.destination_data_spaces dds
    on dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id and
       dds.destination_id = prv.boundary_id + cast(pf.boundary_value_on_right as int)
  left join sys.filegroups fg on fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
 union all
select pf.name as [partition_function],
       ps.name as [partition_scheme],
       pf.fanout as [partition_number],
       case when prv.value is null then NULL else '>' end as [relation],
       prv.value as [boundary_value],
       type_name(pp.system_type_id) as [type],
       fg.name as [filegroup],
       case when ps.name is null then NULL else N'IN USE' end as [status]
  from sys.partition_functions pf
  join sys.partition_parameters pp on pp.function_id = pf.function_id
  left join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.function_id = pf.function_id
  left join sys.destination_data_spaces dds
    on dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id and dds.destination_id = pf.fanout 
  left join sys.filegroups fg on fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
  left join sys.partition_range_values prv
    on prv.function_id = pf.function_id and prv.parameter_id = 1 and
       prv.boundary_id = pf.fanout - 1
 where pf.boundary_value_on_right = 0
 union all
select pf.name as [partition_function],
       ps.name as [partition_scheme],
       NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
       fg.name as [filegroup],
       case when dds.destination_id = pf.fanout + 1
            then N'NEXT USED' else N'NOT USED'
       end as [status]
  from sys.partition_functions pf
  join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.function_id = pf.function_id
  join sys.destination_data_spaces dds
    on dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id and
       dds.destination_id > pf.fanout
  join sys.filegroups fg on fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
```

However, when I perform a `SELECT *` on this view in SSMS, I get the error

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: 
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies down in one of the sources used by that view, the system view `sys.partition_range_values`. The `Value` column of this view is of type `SQL_VARIANT`, which can lead to problems with indiscriminate `SELECT *`s, because SQL has to pick a specific type for the resultset, which all the values then need to be coerced to (Thanks to [this blog post](http://hi10tech.blogspot.com/2014/03/efficient-ways-to-select-rows-from.html) for this insight).

You can see for yourself if this is what's causing your problem, by doing

```
SELECT
    function_id
    , boundary_id
    , parameter_id
    , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Value, 'BaseType') AS DataType
FROM
    sys.partition_range_values
;
```

If you have multiple different `DataType`s, and you can imagine there might be problems casting values between them, then that's the problem.

To fix, you can update your helper view so that instead of

```
prv.value as [boundary_value]
```

instead you have

```
CASE SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(prv.Value,'BaseType')
WHEN 'datetimeoffset' THEN CAST(CAST(prv.Value AS datetimeoffset) AS varchar(30)) 
WHEN 'smallint' THEN CAST(CAST(prv.Value AS smallint) AS varchar(30)) 
-- etc as necessary for the types used to partition on in your database
ELSE SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(prv.Value,'BaseType')
ELSE 'Value of type ' + CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(prv.Value,'BaseType') AS varchar(15))
END 
    AS boundary_Value
```

This will give you appropriate textual representations of the partition range values.